# Dockerfile copy jar file from another directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Ι have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ENV JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

The structure of my application is:

```
Demo: 
 --deployment:
   --Dockerfile
 --src/
 --docker-compose.yaml
 --target:
   --app.jar
```

Code snippet from docker-compose file:

```yaml
api:
 container_name: backend
 image: backend
 build:
   context: deployment/
 ports:
   - "8080:8080"
```

When I am putting the Dockerfile in the same directory with the docker-compose and I am changing the docker compose to:

```yaml
api:
 container_name: backend
 image: backend
 build: .
 ports:
   - "8080:8080"
```

Is running as expected. But I want to put the Dockerfile into the deployment folder, since there I have the helm chart and others docker-comopose files which are using this Dockerfile.

My question is:

How I can specify the correct path of the target folder in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot copy anything which is out of the build context. If you want to keep the current project structure a solution would be in your compose file for the `api` service:

```yaml
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: deployment/Dockerfile
```